# Remove attributes from a specific xml message based on attribute value using xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have only basic knowledge in XSLT ans I was wondering how to create a generic XSLT transformation that removes from all nodes the attributes with a predefined value.

This is a sample xml

```
<note>
    <to attribute1="REMOVE" attribute2="Keep it">Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading hAttribute="REMOVE">Reminder</heading>
    <body bAttribute="REMOVE" bAttribute2="Any">Appointment</body>
</note>
```

I would like to semove all attributes with value REMOVE to obtain this output

```
<note>
    <to attribute2="Keep it">Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body bAttribute2="Any">Appointment</body>
</note>
```

Is there a smart way to achieve this without pointing attribute names?

I was not able to test it

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
  <!-- Identity template -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Remove any attribute with value REMOVE -->
  <xsl:template match="@*[.='REMOVE']"/>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWcCf5o

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark the answer as accepted if your question is answered.